# Using Blur and Submit events on the same form

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am still confused about this. Started learning JQuery about a week now and this is what I have:

```
var IsValidUserName = false;

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#txtUserName').blur(function () {

  if ($('#txtUserName').val().match(isNumberLetter) && 
($('#txtUserName').val().length >= 8)) {

            $('#userNameError').removeClass("error").addClass("default");
            $('#txtUserName').removeClass("alert");
            $('#txtUserName + label').removeAttr("id", "lblUserName");
            IsValidUserName = true;
        }
        else {
            $('#userNameError').removeClass("default").addClass("error");
            $('#txtUserName').addClass("alert");
            $('#txtUserName + label').attr("id", "lblUserName");
        }
    });
});
```

Lets say I have another function like above, lets say ***FirstName***:

How do I call this on the submit event? The code works as I need it to when the user leaves a field. Not sure how I can also call this code and also use the variable above to prevent submit if the data entered is invalid.

I need to call the validation above if the user clicks the submit button and stop the submission if the `IsValidUserName` variable is `false`.

Somethings just need a little push.

Thanks my friends.

Guy

Comment: You could always `trigger` the `blur` like this when you submit the form - `$('#txtUserName').blur()`.. and you can change `$('#txtUserName')` **inside** the `blur` function to `$(this)`

Comment: `$('#txtUserName').on("submit", "form", function(event){` `});`

Comment: Adding to @Sergio : `$(document).on("submit", "form", function(event){ $('#txtUserName').blur() });`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could always extract it into a function instead of an anonymous function and pass the reference to the object you want to check. This would give you the added benefit of reusing it for other elements.

```
function validate(ele) {
    var valid;

    if (ele.val().match(isNumberLetter)) && (ele.val().length >= 8)) {
        valid = true;

        // update user here.
    } else {
        valid = false;

        // update user here.
    }

    return valid;
}

$(function(){
    $('#firstName').blur(function(){ validate($(this)); });
    $('#lastName').blur(function(){ validate($(this)); });

    $("yourFrom").submit(function(){
        var firstNameIsValid = validate($('#firstName'));
        var lastNameIsValid = validate($('#lastName'));

        if (!nameIsValid) && (!lastNameIsValid) {
            return false;
            // User has already been updated
        }
    });
});
```

Also, since you are already heavily using javascript for your validation (hope this is convenience and not the only security), you can also disable the submit button entirely until the form meets the proper requirements.

Comment: Thanks everyone: @John I am thinking disabling the submit button until the form is valid is a great idea. I already have some serious Server Side Validation behind the scenes. So JS is simply a matter of usability.